# Flutter-web: Dialog with relative position to button

Tags: flutter, flutter-web

I'm using flutter-web and I'm trying to create a widget that contains emojis, and when the emojis' button is clicked, a dialog must pop just above the pressed button. I don't know how to position this button. I'm posting a screenshot of an example from messenger, in order to be more clear.

[image]

Can anyone please give me hints of creating this dialog? Thank you for your time.

Comment: first you should know that you probably should not use a dialog instead use a positioned widget with transform , get the button coordinates using https://pub.dev/packages/rect_getter and show the positioned widget above the button if you don't get it wait I will add a code snippet

Comment: Read about `RenderObject`, `localToGlobal` method and `OverlayEntry`.

Comment: I got it done by using `RenderObject`, `localToGlobal` and `OverlayEntry`. I found [this](https://medium.com/saugo360/https-medium-com-saugo360-flutter-using-overlay-to-display-floating-widgets-2e6d0e8decb9) article that helped me do the job. Thank you both for your answers